# Настройка запуска файлов в Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

А есть настройка, что бы не переключаться на Current File с main, а по умолчанию запускать Current File в Pycharm?

Comment: нужно чтобы всегда запускался текущий файл или чтобы всегда запускался main? Из формулировки вопроса непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я вас хорошо понял, вы просто хотите запустить ваш проект, не переключаясь на другой файл.

Не надо никакой настройки, это в Pycharm уже существует:

1. **Первый раз** нужно запускать ваш код прямо из **главного** файла (зеленой стрелкой влево, или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   *Pycharm запомнит, что вы запускали,* и изобразит имя в правой<sup>1</sup> верхней части окна, вместе с зеленой стрелкой направо от этого имени:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. **Следующие разы** вы можете запускать код из **любого** файла зеленой стрелкой в верхней правой<sup>1</sup> части окна (или <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

<sup>1</sup> У вас может быть в *левой*.

Comment: можно запускать любым способом из любого места, необязательно прямо из главного файла (у меня, например, там и зеленой стрелки даже нет). Там в менюшке всегда указан последний запущеный файл.

Comment: @Эникейщик, *«Там в менюшке всегда указан последний запущеный файл.»* - потому что вы его уже когда-то запускали **другим** методом — см. пункт 1 моего ответа. Когда вы его еще никогда не запускали, вам не удастся запустить его напр.  из текстового файла (.txt) проекта.

Comment: @Эникейщик, *«(у меня, например, там и зеленой стрелки даже нет)»*. Почему нет? **1.** Потому, что файл данного типа невозможно запустить. **2.** Потому, что вы ее изображение выключили. **3.** Потому, что с вашей инсталляцией что-то не так.

Comment: Я и говорю, что можно запустить **любым** способом, совсеи необязательно из главного файла, как написано у вас в п. 1.

Comment: @Эникейщик, мы, вероятно, не понимаем друг друга. Пусть у вас новый проект, и вы создаете в нем  файл - `main.py` с командой напр. `print("что-то")`, *но пока не запускаете его.* Затем в том же самом проекте создаете другой файл `text.txt` (и заполните его чем то). Теперь скажите мне — как просто запустить `main.py` **любым** способом, не переключаясь из файла `text.txt`? (Да, можно вручную создать конфигурацию для проекта, но это ни простой, ни **любой** способ.)

Comment: Ребята, вообще-то спрашивал о следующем: у меня в проекте есть два файла один main.py, а другой other.py. main.py, файл я закрыл и работаю с other.py. И вот когда следующий раз я запускаю Pycharm и у меня открывается other.py, то для запуска файла other.py мне надо выбрать перед зелененькой стрелочкой в окошке Current File, потому-что там стоит main

Comment: @ВладимирЕгоров, а вы попробовали сделать то, что я написал в моем ответе? Или нет? Или попробовали, а не работает?

Comment: Уважаемый MarianD, у меня в Pycharm возле нумерации строк кода нет зеленой стрелочки как у Вас на скрине. А единственная зеленая стрелочка при ее нажатии сразу запускает файл main

Comment: Уважаемый Владимир Егоров, зеленая стрелочка возле нумерации строк появляется только для файлов, которые возможно запускать. Но она не так важна, потому что — как я писал в моем ответе — ее используете только один раз и вместо ней вы можете применить Ctrl+Shift+F10.  Важен второй пункт моего ответа — работает он для вас так, как вы хотели?